# Insertar contenido entre párrafos en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Necesitaría saber como puedo reemplazar un contenido entre párrafos con php (vanilla).

Creo sería algo similar a un shortcode en wordpress.

Por ejemplo reemplazar dentro de un parrafo ingresado desde en un editor algún codigo o etiqueta.

EJ: Cuando dentro del párrafo encuentro por ejemplo la etiqueta "[5684]", me reemplace eso por una función que llame a ese id para algo, ejemplo insertar una nota relacionada entre párrafos.

Espero se entienda, muchas gracias!

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p> 
[5684]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

donde vá el código o etiqueta agregada reemplazar por cualquier función.

Ejemplo practico:

https://www.elonce.com/secciones/policiales/666323-rosario-uno-de-los-dos-delincuentes-muertos-haba-estado-preso-por-homicidio.htm
(La nota relacionada, entre los parrafos)

Comment: Jorge, bienvenido a la comunidad. Tu pregunta está mal formulada desde la perspectiva de las normas: Te sugiero hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te des una idea de como funciona la dinámica del sitio. Agrega el código que has intentado y así evitas que te cierren la pregunta.

Comment: Hola, quizás este articulo te pueda ayudar [Link del Articulo](https://hormigasenlanube.com/insertar-tus-anuncios-tras-un-parrafo-determinado/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así (está explicado en el código con comentarios):

```
<?php
//$texto = "la variable que contiene el texto";

$coincidencias = array();

//Buscas las "etiquetas" con la forma: [numeros]
preg_match_all('/\[[0-9]*\]/', $texto, $coincidencias);

//Las etiquetas encontradas están en el arreglo $coincidencias.

//Buscar en la base de datos con que reemplazar cada etiqueta (tienes que agregar tu la logica).

//Resultado devuelto por la query (ejemplo)
$etiquetas = array("[5684]" => 'ENLACE');

//Por cada etiqueta, reemplazas la etiqueta por el texto o enlace.
foreach($etiquetas as $etiqueta => $reemplazo) {
    $texto = str_replace($etiqueta, $reemplazo, $texto);
}

?>
```